# While testing API containing pagination in postman facing skip value error

Tags: javascript, node.js, pagination, backend, middleware

I am using pagination middleware in my node js project but while testing api in postman it's throwing error skip value

Followed the paginate docs but still no use
[image: While testing api in which pagination is applied it's throwing error]

below is my pagination middleware

```
    const pagination = (model) => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page);

    if (page < 1 || page == undefined) {
      page = 1;
    }
    if (limit < 1 || limit == undefined) {
      limit = 2;
    }
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;
    const result = {};
    model.countDocuments({}, (err, count) => {
      const lengthOfDB = count;
      if (endIndex < lengthOfDB) {
        result.next = {
          page: page + 1,
          //limit: limit,
        };
      }
    }).clone();

    if (startIndex > 0) {
      result.previous = {
        page: page - 1,
        //limit: limit,
      };
    }
    try {
      result.result = await model.find().limit(limit).skip(startIndex).exec();
      res.json(result);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `page` is not provided in the query, it will end up being `NaN`, since this code does not cover that case:

```
// 'req.query.page' is undefined
let page = parseInt(req.query.page);
if (page < 1 || page == undefined) {
    page = 1;
}
// 'page' is now equal to NaN
```

A correct way to handle this could be:

```
let page = parseInt(req.query.page);
if (page < 1 || isNaN(page)) {
    page = 1;
}
```